# Is dtruss missing calls?

Tags: java, macos, dtruss

#### Problem

I'm trying to diagnose a problem starting up an application using JCEF on Mac and it seems like `dtruss` is missing system calls from its trace. For example the program always quits after failing to look up 'icudtl.dat', and prints out a log message like this:

```
[0309/151839:ERROR:icu_util.cc(144)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle
```

However only occasically do I see the corresponding write call in the dtruss trace. And I have never managed to capture it actually looking for 'icudtl.dat'. Is it possible for dtruss to miss calls? And if so how can I fix that?

#### Details

Running dtruss like this:

```
sudo dtruss -f ./program.sh 2> /tmp/trace.txt
```

In the trace I see the following:

```
[0309/151839:ERROR:icu_util.cc(144)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle
[0309/151839:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(721)] Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU(). 
dtrace: 1346 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
1403/0xd0ba6:  psynch_cvwait(0x7FBB82435768, 0x14990100149A00, 0x149900)                = 0 0
```

Then much later the write is actually captured:

```
1403/0xd0b93:  write_nocancel(0x2, "[0309/151839:ERROR:icu_util.cc(144)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle\n\0", 0x44)             = 68 0
1403/0xd0b93:  open_nocancel("\0", 0x209, 0x1B6)                = -1 Err#2
1403/0xd0b93:  write_nocancel(0x2, "[0309/151839:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(721)] Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU(). \n\0", 0x5C)             = 9
```

But there is no reference to it trying to look up 'icudtl.dat' at all. Lots of other file IO operations are captured though.

Comment: Well you could opt to print all details `-a` and/or follow backtraces `-s`.

Comment: @l'L'l even when I run with '-asf' it still seems to be missing calls. I also tried increasing the buffer size but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: Maybe try using the `pid` instead, or opensnoop (i.e.`sudo opensnoop -ve`)

Comment: Using the pid doesn't make any difference. Using opensnoop or iosnoop it manages to capture far more of the IO operations but still drops some at the key point I'm interested in. I tried setting the buffer size gradually up to 1GB but it didn't seem to drop any fewer operations which seems strange.